# Solving a second order non linear differential equation

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

So I have to solve this differential equation 
$$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda ^2}+\frac{1}{2r}\bigg(\frac{r}{2M}-1\bigg)^{-1}(E^2-r^2)=0$$
where $M, E$ are constants in above equation.

Putting it in Mathematica do tell it is solvable but it's closed-form will be given in following term $\lambda=f(r)$. Now this gives an idea to change the first term in reverse order i.e. $$\frac{d^2r}{d\lambda ^2}=-\bigg(\frac{d\lambda}{dr}\bigg)^{-3}\frac{d^2\lambda}{dr^2}$$
but it doesn't help. So can anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 1):

Your idea is good. Reducing the order $p=\lambda'$ and $p=\frac 1 {\sqrt z}$, we end with
$$\frac{E^2-r^2}{ r \left(\frac{r}{2 M}-1\right)}+z'=0$$ which is rather simple to integrate.
$$z=c_1-\left(E^2-4 M^2\right) \log (r-2 M)+E^2 \log (r)+2 M r$$
Now, starts the nightmare !